# Create Clustered Index on (Date + Key)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a transaction table that have 40 millions of data. There are 100 columns in the table.

For simply, there are 3 important columns (HeaderID, HeaderLineID, OrderDate) and the unique identifier is (HeaderID, HeaderLineID).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Table](
[HeaderID] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
[HeaderLineID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[OrderDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [FG_Index]

GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [OrderDate] ON [dbo].[T_Table] 
(
    [OrderDate] ASC
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Key] ON [dbo].[T_Table] 
(
    [HeaderID] ASC,
    [HeaderLineID] ASC
)
GO
```

For normal usage, we select the data based on date range

```
select * from T_Table
where OrderDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
```

Is it better approach to drop current keys and insert a clustered index key with Date + Key instead? That is,

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [NewKey] ON [dbo].[T_Table] 
(
    [OrderDate] ASC,
    [HeaderID] ASC,
    [HeaderLineID] ASC
)
GO
```

.

**Replies from comments**

> explain what is HeaderID and HeaderLineID. Is combination of HeaderLineID & HeaderID unique?

HeaderID is the Order Number and HeaderLineID is the Order Line Number.

Combination of HeaderID+HeaderLineID is unique.

> Which will be most frequently use in search ? Selectivity of Order Date vs Selectivity of HeaderLineID & HeaderID.

OrderDate could be found in filter condition

HeaderLineID could be found in joining condition to other tables

HeaderID, HeaderLineID, OrderDate could be found in output result

Comment: explain what is HeaderID and HeaderLineID.Is combination of HeaderLineID & HeaderID unique. ?Which will be most frequently use in search ? Selectivity of Order Date vs Selectivity of HeaderLineID & HeaderID.

Answer (score 0):

Your index will not perform good ,for the queries you have,if your order date is not unique and if you  have more queries like below

```
select * from T_Table
where OrderDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
```

i suggest creating a non clustered index with below definition

```
create index nci_somename on t_table(orderdate)
include(HeaderID, HeaderLineID)
```

Having a clustered index is good,but i don't recommend it ,if it won't satisfy your queries

Comment: I would like to know if using a clustered index (Date + Key) is good and useful in normal practice. For other queries, the (HeaderID, HeaderLineID) is used in joining conditions

Answer (score 0):

i) What is the volume of transaction per date ?

ii) You must hv read this example where table scan was done instead of CI seek becasue optmizer felt table scan was more cose effective way.Similarly can be your case.

iii) Critical error: 100 column in single table is itself wrong.For how many column you include in NON Clustered covering index.At most 20-25 column are comonn and important across all req. rest column are AREA specific  hence mostly sparse.Putting all columns in single table is not an example of DeNormalization.

iv) Is data really normalise ?I mean do you hv repeative rows.for example suppose two item was ordered in single orderid then how it is stored in this scenario.If two item are store in same table then it is not an example of DeNormalization.

v) Create CI on unique sequential column. Create Non Clsutered index on OrderDate include (*some common important column)
*since no idea about rest column and details.

Comment: "100 column in single table is itself wrong" - that's incorrect in general

Comment: i) Around 20k records per date

iii, iv) The table is data source. We extract data from this table everyday